# MVC getting null parameter error when posting to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this method in my mvc controller:

```
public void RejectInvoice(int invoiceId)
        {
            var invoice = _unitOfWork.InvoiceRepository.Get((int)invoiceId);

            invoice.Rejected = true;
            invoice.RejectedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            _unitOfWork.InvoiceRepository.InsertUpdate(invoice);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
        }
```

In my script file I call it using:

```
$.post('/Invoice/RejectInvoice/'+ 3, function (data) {

                    });
```

In firebug I'm getting:

[image]

What the ...........? It clearly shows I've provided it with the 3 as a parameter but then claims I'm sending it a null?

can someone tell me what is going on here? How to fix?

Comment: can you show us your routing table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default model binder will bind to a parameter called "id" but your parameter is named invoiceId, so it does not know to bind the value to it. A quick fix would be to change your POST URL to `'/Invoice/RejectInvoice/?invoiceId='+ 3`.

Comment: Or, change your parameter to RejectInvoice(int id)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a post you should also decorated your methods the [HttpPost] attribute and 
check the sent parameters, my suggestion would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public void RejectInvoice(FormCollection collection)
{
    var id = -1;
    if(int.TryParse(collection["invoiceId"], out id))
    {
        var invoice = _unitOfWork.InvoiceRepository.Get(id);

        invoice.Rejected = true;
        invoice.RejectedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        _unitOfWork.InvoiceRepository.InsertUpdate(invoice);
        _unitOfWork.Save();         
    }

}
```

as for the jquery:

```
$.post("/Invoice/RejectInvoice/", { invoiceId: "3"}, callback );
```

(I think, it been a while since I last used $.post)